# How to get getGridParam("postData").filters equivalent in PQGrid

Tags: jquery

I am using https://paramquery.com/API#method-search. How do I get `JQGrid.getGridParam("postData").filters` equivalent in **PQGrid**? My objective here is to get all filter and sorting information from the grid and use it for save the state for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally. `$( "selector" ).pqGrid( "saveState")`. This returns the JSON of current state of the grid. That can be used.